# jQuery-ui Tooltip get Title on click

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm working with jquery-ui. I can create elements with titles and show the titles. However on a click, I would like to take the title and populate another div (this is because touch enabled devices do not have tooltips). I can get a click event, but I can't get the title while in the click event.

```
  $("div").click(function( event ) {
      // just to prove that we are entering this event
      $("#preShow").html ( Date() );

      // show the title
      var toolTip = this.attributes.title.value;
      $("#show").html ( toolTip );

      // just to prove that there was no crash
      $("#postShow").html ( Date() );
  });
```

I have also tried using

```
  var toolTip = $(this).attr ("title");
```

Here is the jsfiddle showing the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/jK5xQ/

The same code works **if** I create an HTML file and run it in Firefox with a breakpoint at the first line of the click event. Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because jQueryUI's Tooltip removes the title and uses it.  Try going about it like this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( document ).tooltip( {
        track:    true,
        content:  function() {
            return  $( this ).attr( "title" );
        }
    });      
    $('div').click(function(){
        $('#show').html($('#' + $(this).attr('aria-describedby')).children().html());
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jK5xQ/4/

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Old question but for anyone else looking for this I would propose saving the current title in a data attribute on the element instead of looking for the aria-descriedby-tag. For instance we're using some custom HTML inside the tooltip that would screw up the proposed solution. Easiest way of solving it is adding something like `$(this).data('current-title', element.attr('title'));` to the content function and then look for that data-attribute on click, if it does not exist use title instead.